# DialogFragment with AppCompatDialog crashes if STYLE_NO_TITLE is set

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-dialogfragment, android-appcompat

I'm trying to use the new material-themed dialogs with fragments in AppCompat v22.1. [According to Chris Banes](https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/#comment-1981390448), to do this:

> Just return `new AppCompatDialog(getActivity(), getTheme())` from
>   `onCreateDialog(Bundle)`.

Setting this up:

```
public class MyFragment extends DialogFragment
{
    public MyFragment() { }

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AppCompatDialog(getActivity(), getTheme());
    }

    ...
}
```

works perfectly in the normal case; the dialog is correctly themed and everything. However, when we try to show a dialog with the [`STYLE_NO_TITLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#STYLE_NO_TITLE) option:

```
 MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
 fragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
 fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DIALOG");
```

it causes the following exception and crash:

```
05-19 12:18:38.806  15458-15458/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.test.testdialog, PID: 15458
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:302)
    at android.app.Dialog.requestWindowFeature(Dialog.java:1066)
    at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:317)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I guess the problem might be related to `DialogFragment` calling `requestWindowFeature()` instead of `supportRequestWindowFeature()` (?)

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: is it related to this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=170053 ?

Comment: @Blackbelt Yes, it's definitely the same, thanks.

Comment: return new AppCompatDialog(getActivity()) works for me, and the default style does not have a title, so there is not need to set  STYLE_NO_TITLE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in AppCompat v22.1 which was [fixed in v22.1.1](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=170053).

It broke again in v23 and [was fixed once more, in v23.0.1](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183186).

It's working ok as of this writing.

Comment: any idea about this fragment dialog crash with v23.0.1?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32813894/v7-support-23-0-1-crash-appcompatbutton-setbackgrounddrawable

Answer (score 2):

According to issues from link of Blackbelt we should return AppCompatDialog and use supportRequestWindowFeature(). I propose change like this:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AppCompatDialog dialog = new AppCompatDialog(getActivity(), getTheme());
    return dialog;
}

@Override
public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
    switch (style) {
        case STYLE_NO_INPUT:
            dialog.getWindow().addFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
            // fall through...
        case STYLE_NO_FRAME:
        case STYLE_NO_TITLE:
            ((AppCompatDialog) dialog).supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    }
}
```

or better, try not to touch original code:

```
@Override
public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog,style);
    if(style == STYLE_NO_TITLE) 
         ((AppCompatDialog) dialog).supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, this was a bug in the support library and has already been fixed.