# v7 support 23.0.1 crash: AppCompatButton.setBackgroundDrawable

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-dialogfragment

I am experiencing this crash, with support library 23.0.1

It happens when showing a Dialog Fragment.

It verifies with both `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment` and `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialogFragment`

Anyone else is experiencing this?

It always happens with release compilation (which has Proguard enabled), and only in some cases with debug compilation.

I am reporting the crash stacks for both fragment classes.

stack for **android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment**:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #115: Error inflating class Button
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
       at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:235)
       at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:356)
       at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:373)
       at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
       at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onStart(SourceFile:406)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1060)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1207)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(SourceFile:738)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(SourceFile:1572)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(SourceFile:493)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.o.a()' on a null object reference
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.setBackgroundDrawable(SourceFile:85)
       at android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:16226)
       at android.view.View.(View.java:4103)
       at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:637)
       at android.widget.Button.(Button.java:111)
       at android.widget.Button.(Button.java:107)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.(SourceFile:64)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.(SourceFile:60)
       at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(SourceFile:101)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(SourceFile:966)
       at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(SourceFile:44)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
       at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:235)
       at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:356)
       at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:373)
       at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
       at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onStart(SourceFile:406)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1060)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1207)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(SourceFile:738)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(SourceFile:1572)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(SourceFile:493)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

stack for **android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialogFragment**:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class Button
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
       at eu.baroncelli.oraritrenitalia.mainactivity.AlertDialogFragment.onCreateView(SourceFile:62)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(SourceFile:1962)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1026)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1207)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(SourceFile:738)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(SourceFile:1572)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(SourceFile:493)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.o.a()' on a null object reference
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.setBackgroundDrawable(SourceFile:85)
       at android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:16226)
       at android.view.View.(View.java:4103)
       at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:637)
       at android.widget.Button.(Button.java:111)
       at android.widget.Button.(Button.java:107)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.(SourceFile:64)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.(SourceFile:60)
       at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(SourceFile:101)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(SourceFile:966)
       at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(SourceFile:44)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
       at eu.baroncelli.oraritrenitalia.mainactivity.AlertDialogFragment.onCreateView(SourceFile:62)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(SourceFile:1962)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1026)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1207)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(SourceFile:738)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(SourceFile:1572)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(SourceFile:493)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Open proguard mapping file and tell us what's `android.support.v7.widget.o.a()`. Have you tried [this](https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/issues/17)?

Comment: Thanks!!! I solved it by adding:
`-keep public class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }`

Comment: @EugenPechanec, I can award you the answer if you write one

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/issues/17) your proguard setup should contain the following rules if you're using appcompat-v7:

```
-keep public class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.** { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
}
```

This will also save you from trouble when using SearchView and other things I imagine.

Comment: That being said unless you messed up proguard configuration you don't need this (at least with 25.x.x support library).

Comment: I am using the support library v27 and this was still needed. I removed everything from my old proguard and had the bare minimum. I ensured that I was loading the default proguard file, and then had separate files for some libs that I used. Given this, when I removed this config for support libs, my app always crashed.